# phpQuery: タグの内容を変更できません

Tags: php, html

目標は、既に作ってある`php`ファイルにおいてタグの内容を差し替えるという事です。
インタネットに見つけた例通り作ったのに、元のファイルには変化がありません。

```
$doc = phpQuery::newDocumentFile("../".$filename); // こちらは問題なし、私の場合ファイルの名前はtest.phpです。
$title = $doc['title']; // 問題ありません、echo $title->text();は正常に表示してくれます
$title->text("content"); // 効果ありません
$doc->find('#test')->append('some content'); // 効果ありません
```

最後の行はIDだけ取り替えて[こちら](http://codingexplained.com/coding/php/manipulating-dom-documents-with-phpquery)の例通りにしました。
コードを掲載致します。

**index.php**

```
<?php 
    require 'phpQuery0.9.5.php'; 
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>phpQuery代入試験</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
</head>

<body>

<?php 

    $filename = 'test.php'; 
    echo "ファイル名:".$filename."<br />";

    $doc = phpQuery::newDocumentFile($filename);
    echo "ドキュメント内容: <br />".$doc."<hr />";

    $title = $doc['title'];
    echo "ページ見出し: ".$title->text()."<br />";

    $new_title = "成功";
    echo $new_title."に取り替えます";

    // 方法１
    $title->text($new_title);

    // 方法２
    $title = $doc->find('title');
    $title->text($new_title);   
?>

</body>
</html>
```

**test.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>こちらを差し替えましょう</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
</head>

<body>
    <div id="test"> こちらを差し替えましょう </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

質問の意味がイマイチ理解できないのですがどういうことでしょう。元ファイルが変わらない、という意味ですか？

上記のコードを要点だけ抜き出して実行してみたところ問題はなさそうですが……

```
<?php
    require __DIR__.'/phpQuery-onefile.php';
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>phpQuery代入試験</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
</head>

<body>

<?php

    $filename = 'test.php';
    echo "ファイル名:".$filename."<br />";

    $doc = phpQuery::newDocumentFile($filename);

    $doc['title']->text('content');
    $doc->find('#test')->append('some content'); // 効果ありません
?>
<xmp><?= $doc ?></xmp>
</body>
</html>
```

result:

```
ファイル名:test.php

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8">
<title>content</title>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
</head>
<body>
    <div id="test"> こちらを差し替えましょう some content</div>

</body>
</html>
```

---

ファイルに書き込むならこれで可能ですね。

```
<?php
    require __DIR__.'/phpQuery-onefile.php';

    $filename = 'test.php';
    $doc = phpQuery::newDocumentFile($filename);

    $doc['title']->text('content');
    $doc->find('#test')->append('some content');

    $out = 'output.html';
    file_put_contents($out, $doc);
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ja">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>test</title>
</head>
<body>
    <p>input: <?=$filename ?></p>
    <p>output: <?=$out ?></p>
</body>
</html>
```

inputとoutputのファイル名を分けていますが、同じにしても構いません。

Comment: 曖昧に質問を聞いてしまい、大変申し訳ありませんでした。はい、その通りです。望ましい結果は元のファイルを変えるということです。ご丁寧に掲載した解決には、`<xmp><?= $doc ?></xmp>`を要求すると、`<title>`が変わったように表示されますけど、元のファイルは変わらないままです。もしかして、何をしても`phpQuery`は元のファイルに影響がないでしょうか。

Comment: はい、当然です。これはファイルの中身を読み込んでメモリ上でDOMを変更してるだけなので、ファイルを書き換えるには明示的に書き込む必要があります

Comment: 「明示的に‌​書き込む」とは、`fopen`->正規表現->`str_replace`->`fclose`というような方法ですか。

Comment: ファイルに書き込む例を追記しました。

Comment: 完璧です、これで解決です。お忙しいところ、回答してくださいまして、誠にありがとうございます。